# Using a struct to store dynamic data

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm fairly new to Swift programming and I have been following an online tutorial to create a bar chart from static dummy data using a struct. Below is the dummy data:

```
private static func createDummyData() -> [ChartViewData] {

    let one = ChartViewData(date: "2/5/19", weight: 50)
    let two = ChartViewData(date: "3/5/19", weight: 60)
    let three = ChartViewData(date: "4/5/19", weight: 65)
    let four = ChartViewData(date: "8/5/19", weight: 55)
    let five = ChartViewData(date: "9/5/19", weight: 100)

    return[one, two, three, four, five]
}
```

My struct is defined as:

```
struct ChartViewData {
    var date: String
    var weight: Double
}
```

I would like to use my own data stored in arrays **date** and **weight** to populate the bar chart. What is the best approach to do this without changing the working chart model and struct?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: My apologies everyone, I meant store not sort in the question title!

Comment: First: Are you sure you want to deal with `date` property as a `String`? What about `Date`?  Second: could you please mention the expected result based on your example?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ChartViewData` instances by `zip`ping the arrays and `map` them

```
let dateArray = ["2/5/19", "3/5/19", "4/5/19", "8/5/19", "9/5/19"]
let weightArray = [50.0, 60.0, 65.0, 55.0, 100.0]

let chartData = zip(dateArray, weightArray).map(ChartViewData.init)
print(chartData)
```

The date format "d/M/yy" is unsuitable to sort the dates. Either use string format "yy/MM/dd" or declare the `date` member as `Date`.

Comment: Sorry @vadian, I meant store in the question title, not sort

Comment: What does *store* mean? The code in the answer creates an array of `ChartViewData` instances from the mentioned arrays in the question.

Comment: `let one = ChartViewData(date: "2/5/19", weight: 50)`
but rather than the value of _date_ and _weight_  being static, I would like to iterate through their corresponding arrays, **date** and **weight**. So, for instance,
`let barData = ChartViewData(date: date[i], weight: weight[i])`

Comment: Your syntax makes no sense. Either use two arrays (not recommended) or use the code in my answer to map the arrays to `ChartViewData` instances

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own data stored in arrays **date** and **weight** to populate the bar chart, by iterating the array. First change `createDummyData` method like this

```
private static func createDummyData(dateArray: [String], weightArray: [Double]) -> [ChartViewData] {
    var dataArray: [ChartViewData] = []
    for i in 0..<dateArray.count {
        let barData = ChartViewData(date: dateArray[i], weight: weightArray[i])
        dataArray.append(barData)
    }
    return dataArray
}
```

And while calling this method pass your arrays as parameter

```
YourClassName.createDummyData(dateArray: date, weightArray: weight)
```

---

You can change the method even shorter

```
private static func createDummyData(dateArray: [String], weightArray: [Double]) -> [ChartViewData] {
    return zip(dateArray,weightArray).map { ChartViewData(date: $0, weight: $1) }
}
```